# Canadian extended stay in the United States

Tags: international-travel, overstaying, long-stay-visas

I'm planning on going to the United States for a six month course in dog training.  I've already spent a week in the states this calendar year.  I'll also probably be in the states for the dog training a few days before and after it starts.  As a Canadian citizen what kind of documentation do I need?

Comment: You are not limited to six months per calendar year, but six months per visit, as far as immigration law is concerned. If your question is about visiting the US for slightly longer than six months, then it is probably a good fit for this site. You should also be concerned about tax implications, though; your presence in the US might turn you into a US tax resident.  Questions about that should go to [Expatriates.SE]. You should also consider whether the course is an acceptable "visitor" activity or whether you need to seek a *student* immigration status to enroll. That also belongs at expats.

Comment: @phoog do you mean 6 months in a twelve-month period?

Comment: @Dorothy no, I do not.  In the US, visitor time limits are per visit.  There's a "rule of thumb" that visitors should spend no more than half of their time in the US, but it's just that: a rule of thumb, and the window in which to calculate the proportion of time in the US is not fixed.

Comment: Are you going to be student in the dog training course, or are you teaching it (and subsequently receiving money)?

Comment: @MichaelC. "Going for a course" strongly implies attending as a student.